# Equivalent function ibwrtfW and ibwrtfA in python visa/gpib module

Tags: python, visa, gpib

I'm in the process of automating lab instruments.
I have a requirement like function will send file/binary data via VISA GPIB from Host PC to instrument.

In Ni4882.h there is the following functions to transfer file/binary data in Visual studio 2010, and it is working. I have well versed in the sending command as GPIB string.

But I never came across sending the file through GPIB command.

These are functions I tried in c++.  I used ni4882.obj file (have the definition of these functions) and created an application, So I was able to  transfer a file PC to instruments. But I am not able to find equivalent functions in python

```
unsigned long NI488CC ibwrtfA  (int ud, const char * filename);
unsigned long NI488CC ibwrtfW  (int ud, const wchar_t * filename);
```

Could anyone please let me know the equivalent function in pyvisa or visa python package? --or-- any equivalent module to an alternative for this.

I browse through all the functions of pyvisa and visa, but I failed to find the equivalent functions.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Sandy, do you have a working code in C/C++ for handling this task? If you have, your chances of a helpful answer would increase if you include it in your question.

Comment: @ArtonDorneles I have ni4882.h and ni4882.obj object file from standrad NI installation of the driver. Please do visit the link http://www.ni.com/download/ni-488.2-3.1.2/4360/en/

Comment: Did you try my answer?  Drop me a line if I can do anything else for you.

Comment: @ArtonDorneles I tried this option but i got type error exception

Comment: Could you post the output of the error here? Maybe I can help you solve that.

Comment: Error is as follows   ret = library.viWrite(session, data, len(data), byref(return_count))
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2

Comment: Are you reading data this way? `data = list(f.read())` ? If yes, try to switch to `data = f.read()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the method [write_raw](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/resources.html?highlight=write_ascii_values#pyvisa.resources.GPIBInstrument.write_raw). Try out this code:

```
import visa
rm = visa.ResourceManager()

rm.list_resources() # ('ASRL1::INSTR', 'ASRL2::INSTR', 'GPIB0::12::INSTR')
ud = rm.open_resource('GPIB0::12::INSTR') #You need to specify your device here.

#Read the file into data
f = open('file.dat', 'rb')
data = list(f.read())

#Write file into device
ud.write_raw(data)
```

As alternative to `write_raw` you can try [write_binary_values](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/resources.html?highlight=write_binary_values#pyvisa.resources.GPIBInstrument.write_binary_values) or [write_ascii_values](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/stable/api/resources.html?highlight=write_ascii_values#pyvisa.resources.GPIBInstrument.write_ascii_values). Both provide more settings if you need.